# Azure B2C Scope - Restrict Access to Data Specific to a user

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to restrict access of user to particular objects say specific classrooms say  class room A and Class room B.  My understanding is that I can have a B2C scope say 
AccessClassRoom but not specific Class Rooms.   For User Specific data I should not use scopes.  Let me know if my understanding is correct

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Permissions/roles and scopes provide the two halves for this user access control.

Scopes -- such as `AccessClassRoom` -- determine whether an authorized application can access data on behalf of an authorizing/consenting user if this user, through their permission/role assignment/s, is permitted to do so.

Azure AD B2C doesn't have any current support for managing permissions/roles and assignments of them to users.

It does, however, have support for managing scopes and assignments of them to applications.